# Selection menu in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, menu, selection

is it possible to have a batch script to ask the user (within CMD) to select if the current PC is a host or client?
The user uses the up or down keyboard arrows to select an option and hits enter to confirm it.

Ive Done a little googling but I can only find code for entering a selection number.

Comment: Write a simple `VBsript`, use `WshShell.Popup` and `WScript.Quit (exitcode)` methods... By the way, do you see an user **knows** _if the current PC is a host or client_? And if knows, does the right reply?

Comment: @JosefZ yes the user runs the setup program and selects if his pc is a host or client, he should run he program on at least one client after running it on the host. The program sets up roaming profiles over a workgroup instead of a domain, if he selects host then it jumps to the block of code labeled :host and ends in the right place and if he selects 'client' it jumps to the label :client and ends in correct place too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way that a Batch file can read a cursor control key without the aid of a third party program. However, you may use an interesting trick based on DOSKEY command via this procedure:

1. Clear previous DOSKEY history.
2. Execute several SET /P commands that read the menu options, so the DOSKEY history is filled with them.
3. Send a F7 key to the keyboard.
4. Execute a SET /P "OPTION=Prompt: "; the input to this command will be completed via the selection menu of DOSKEY.

Although this method requires the aid of JScript programming language, it is included with all Windows versions from XP on. Copy and paste the code below as a Batch .BAT file:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Multi-line menu with options selection via DOSKEY
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Define the options
set numOpts=0
for %%a in (First Second Third Fourth Fifth) do (
   set /A numOpts+=1
   set "option[!numOpts!]=%%a Option"
)
set /A numOpts+=1
set "option[!numOpts!]=exit"

rem Clear previous doskey history
doskey /REINSTALL
rem Fill doskey history with menu options
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0" EnterOpts
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numOpts%) do set /P "var="

:nextOpt
cls
echo MULTI-LINE MENU WITH OPTIONS SELECTION
echo/
rem Send a F7 key to open the selection menu
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~F0"
set /P "var=Select the desired option: "
echo/
if "%var%" equ "exit" goto :EOF
echo Option selected: "%var%"
pause
goto nextOpt


@end

var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    envVar = wshShell.Environment("Process"),
    numOpts = parseInt(envVar("numOpts"));

if ( WScript.Arguments.Length ) {
   // Enter menu options
   for ( var i=1; i <= numOpts; i++ ) {
      wshShell.SendKeys(envVar("option["+i+"]")+"{ENTER}");
   }
} else {
   // Enter a F7 to open the menu
   wshShell.SendKeys("{F7}{HOME}");
}
```

Output example of previous program:

[image: Output example of previous program]

Further details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661).

Comment: Thanks alot!, anyway to remove the numbers from the list at all?

Comment: I was having issues with the menu appearing automatically, but fixed it after switching to the legacy version of cmd [(details here)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32908.command-prompt-improvements-in-windows-10.aspx). Also, I found info suggesting resetting the doskey listsize instead of a reinstall [(info here)](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5982), but doing so also requires cmd legacy version.

Comment: @Mistella: I invite you to review the [last version of this program](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661&p=60123#p59916).